# Angular material tree view

Tags: angular, angular-material, web-frontend

I'm trying to work with the angular material tree view but I got an error on the console and the page display is blank without any list

[image: This is error on console]

and on my app.component.html

```
        <cdk-tree [dataSource]="nestedDataSource" [treeControl]="nestedTreeControl">
        <cdk-nested-tree-node *cdkTreeNodeDef="let node" class="example-tree-node">
            <button mat-icon-button disabled></button> {{node.filename}}: {{node.type}}
        </cdk-nested-tree-node>
        <cdk-nested-tree-node *cdkTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasNestedChild" class="example-tree-node">
            <button mat-icon-button [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.filename" cdkTreeNodeToggle>
            <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
              {{nestedTreeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
            </mat-icon>
          </button> {{node.filename}}: {{node.type}}
            <div [class.example-tree-invisible]="!nestedTreeControl.isExpanded(node)">
                <ng-container cdkTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
            </div>
        </cdk-nested-tree-node>
    </cdk-tree>
```

Am i missing a step

Comment: i gues CdkTreeModule is not imported into your module

Comment: i allready import on app.module

Answer (score 0):

Try to import `NestedTreeControl` in your app.component.ts . Your code should be similar to the below attached code.

AND

Check whether you have added `CdkTreeModule` in exports list in app.module.ts.

```js
import {
  ArrayDataSource
} from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import {
  Component
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  NestedTreeControl
} from '@angular/cdk/tree';

/**
 * Food data with nested structure.
 * Each node has a name and an optional list of children.
 */
interface FoodNode {
  name: string;
  children ? : FoodNode[];
}

const TREE_DATA: FoodNode[] = [{
    name: 'Fruit',
    children: [{
      name: 'Apple'
    }, {
      name: 'Banana'
    }, {
      name: 'Fruit loops'
    }],
  },
  {
    name: 'Vegetables',
    children: [{
        name: 'Green',
        children: [{
          name: 'Broccoli'
        }, {
          name: 'Brussels sprouts'
        }],
      },
      {
        name: 'Orange',
        children: [{
          name: 'Pumpkins'
        }, {
          name: 'Carrots'
        }],
      },
    ],
  },
];

/**
 * @title Tree with nested nodes
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'cdk-tree-nested-example',
  templateUrl: 'cdk-tree-nested-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['cdk-tree-nested-example.css'],
})
export class CdkTreeNestedExample {
  treeControl = new NestedTreeControl < FoodNode > (node => node.children);
  dataSource = new ArrayDataSource(TREE_DATA);

  hasChild = (_: number, node: FoodNode) => !!node.children && node.children.length > 0;
}
```

Comment: I have to try to add but it throws the same error